# Manipulating RTF files with GAS (to gdoc, en masse)

Tags: google-apps-script, rtf

Is there a way to programmatically convert RTF files to gdocs, or if you can't convert then just copy the contents? I have hundreds to store in gdrive so I'd prefer to convert them to make them easier to manipulate and merge later.

Comment: Do any of these files exceed 50MB?

Comment: No, definitely not, they are generally a few paragraphs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to convert RTF file to Google Document.
- There are several hundreds of RTF files.

If my understanding is correct, how about this sample script?

As a simple conversion, you can use the script of `Drive.Files.copy({mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS}, fileId)` using Advanced Google Service. But from your question, I thought that when a lot of files are converted, the execution time might be over 6 minutes. So in this sample script, I conver the files with the files.copy method of Drive API using Batch request.

### Sample script:

When you run the script, please set the parameters to the function of `main()`. And run `main()`.

```
// Get file IDs of Microsoft Excel files in a specific folder including subfolders.
function getFileIds(folder, fileIds, q) {
  var files = folder.searchFiles(q);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    fileIds.push(files.next().getId());
  }
  var folders = folder.getFolders();
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    getFileIds(folders.next(), fileIds, q);
  }
  return fileIds;
}

// Convert Microsoft Docs to Google Docs
function convertToGoogleDocs(fileIds, dest, to) {
  var limit = 100;
  var split = Math.ceil(fileIds.length / limit);
  var reqs = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < split; i++) {
    var boundary = "xxxxxxxxxx";
    var payload = fileIds.splice(0, limit).reduce(function(s, e, i) {
      s += "Content-Type: application/http\r\n" +
        "Content-ID: " + i + "\r\n\r\n" +
        "POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + e + "/copy" + "\r\n" +
        "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n" +
        JSON.stringify({"parents": [dest], "mimeType": to}) + "\r\n" +
        "--" + boundary + "\r\n";
      return s;
    }, "--" + boundary + "\r\n");
    var params = {
      method: "post",
      contentType: "multipart/mixed; boundary=" + boundary,
      payload: payload,
      headers: {Authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
      muteHttpExceptions: true,
    };
    var req = UrlFetchApp.getRequest("https://www.googleapis.com/batch/drive/v3", params);
    reqs.push(req);
  }
  return UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(reqs);
}

// Please run this function.
function main() {
  var sourceFolderId = "###"; // Folder ID including source files. Please set this.
  var destinationFolderId = "###"; // Folder ID that the converted files are put. Please set this.

  var from = [MimeType.RTF, MimeType.MICROSOFT_WORD_LEGACY]; // Source mimeType
  var to = MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS; // Destination mimeType
  var q = from.reduce(function(q, e, i) {return q += "mimeType='" + e + "'" + (i < from.length - 1 ? " or " : "")}, "");
  var fileIds = getFileIds(DriveApp.getFolderById(sourceFolderId), [], q);
  Logger.log(fileIds)
  var res = convertToGoogleDocs(fileIds, destinationFolderId, to);
  Logger.log(res);
}
```

### Note:

- If the file size is large, an error might occur.
- When RTF file is retrieved by Drive API, there was the case that the mimeType becomes `application/msword`. So I searched both `application/rtf` and `application/msword`.
- Unfortunately, in the current stage, the batch request cannot use the media blob. So I used the files.copy method. In this case, the files can be converted without using the media blob.

### References:

- [Files: copy](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/copy)
- [Batch request](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/batch)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: thanks for this, I didn't know that you could use conversions during file.copy! i'll try to use this later.

Comment: @J. G. Thank you for replying. When the files.copy method is used for converting the files, the batch request can be used because the media blob is not required to be used. So I used this for your situation.

Comment: @J. G. Is there anything that I can do for your question? If my answer was not useful for your situation. I have to apologize and modify it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. I would like to think of about the solution.

Comment: Marked as solved. I haven't actually gotten to use it because I was waiting on a patch fix for the software I'm getting the rtfs from (scrivener).

Comment: @J. G. Thank you for replying. If you have any questions for about my answer, feel free to tell me.